# How do i change the bower package reference path in the Index.html

Tags: json, angularjs, gruntjs, bower, wiredep

I have this index.html which is referring to a few bower packages. I am using the wiredep. How do I change the reference path of these packages in the index.html using the bower.json. Is there any key I can add in the bower.json that would prefix the dependency package paths.

Right now I have the below lines in my index.html

```
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='bower_components/angular-google-places-autocomplete/src/autocomplete.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='bower_components/angular-google-places-autocomplete/dist/autocomplete.min.css' />
<!-- endbower -->
```

I need to change it to

```
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='static/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='static/bower_components/angular-google-places-autocomplete/src/autocomplete.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='static/bower_components/angular-google-places-autocomplete/dist/autocomplete.min.css' />
<!-- endbower -->
```

just by adding a key and value "static/" or something like that in the bower.json

Comment: you need a .bowerrc file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a .bowerrc file at the root of your project, as explained in [the documentation](http://bower.io/docs/config/), containing

```
{
  "directory": "static/bower_components"
}
```

And bower will then look for and store its components in `static/bower_components`.

Comment: I agree, the bower components get installed inside the "static" folder. But, that isn't changing anything in the index.html after "grunt serve". Index.html is still referring to "bower_components" to load the packages and not "static/bower_components"